# SQL - Remove characters after third occurrence of a comma

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field of authors names all separated by commas, but I only want to be able to select the first three names that appear regardless of how many overall appear in the field; I've got the below code but it isn't working for me:

```
select left(AUTHORS,charindex(',',AUTHORS,charindex(',',AUTHORS,charindex(',',AUTHORS)+1)+1)-1)
```

I get the error

> ORA-00904: "LEFT": invalid identifier

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You are using a SQL Server function and getting an Oracle error.  Provide sample data and desired rsults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(authors, '^([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+).*$', '\1')
```

Comment: This should also work on MySQL 8+ (also one of the original tags) +1

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much and apologies for the lack of data, the work I'm doing is all new to me and I'm figuring it out as I go along.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the result you asked:

```
select NVL(SUBSTR(AUTHORS, 1, INSTR(AUTHORS,',',1,3) -1), AUTHORS)
from mytable;
```

Also in case you have only 2 author names this will return the column value.

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9f5a685b3897c15b490bd5b285384296)